# How to deal with unused qubits in application specific quantum chips?

Tags: qiskit, hardware

## Background

I am a complete novice to quantum hardware but am trying to give myself an introduction to Qiskit Metal. I have set myself the challenge of designing a custom quantum chip for the Bernstein-Vazirani algorithm circuit found below (taken from Qiskit textbook chapter). For $q_2$ below $HIH = I$ which would suggest that it would be safe to completely ignore the qubit since no processing will be done on the chip itself and it doesn't couple with any of the other qubits.

[image: Bernstein-Vazirani Circuit]

## Question

May I safely design a quantum chip for this toy application and omit qubit $q_2$ assuming that its state will be stored unmodified off-chip?